# How to optimize this query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @codeItem VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Price DECIMAL(18, 5);
DECLARE @EndDate DATE;
DECLARE @StartDate DATE;

DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable

OPEN Cur

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @codeItem, @Price, @EndDate, @StartDate

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 BEGIN

    EXEC sp_Proc @codeItem, @Price, @EndDate, @StartDate

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @codeItem, @Price, @EndDate, @StartDate
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur
```

Stored procedure `sp_Proc`:

```
UPDATE SRC
SET enddate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @StartDate)
FROM test SRC
WHERE codeItem = @codeItem
    AND (@StartDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)

INSERT INTO test (codeItem, price, startdate, enddate)
VALUES (@codeItem, @price, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

How can I optimize the queries?

Delete the cursor?

How can I make it faster?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a cursor for this, nor a stored procedure.  Something like this should work:

```
update s
    set EndDate = dateadd(day, -1 , t.StartDate)
    from src s join
         mytable t
         on s.codeItem = t.codeItem and
            (t.StartDate between s.startDate and s.EndDate);

insert into test(codeItem, price, StartDate, EndDate)
    select codeItem, price, StartDate, EndDate
    from myTable;
```

The `update` "closes" the previous record.  The `insert` inserts the new one.  These are set-based operations so they should be much faster than using a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        UPDATE s
        SET enddate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, t.StartDate)
        FROM dbo.test s
        JOIN dbo.myTable t ON s.codeItem = t.codeItem
        WHERE t.StartDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate

        INSERT INTO test (codeItem, price, startdate, enddate)
        SELECT codeItem, price, startdate, enddate
        FROM myTable

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with queries is faster than work with cursors.

For example for your update query you could use this query:

```
 Update SRC set EndDate = dateadd(day,-1, mt.StartDate)
 from test SRC 
 inner join myTable as mt
     on mt.codeItem = SRC.codeItem 
 where mt.StartDate between startDate and EndDate;
```

and for you insert query

```
Insert Into test
select * from myTable;
```